# How to see Lync status of the users in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, lync

is there a way that i see the Communicator status of the Users in excel ?
I deal with so many support teams as part of my daily activities and use Excel a lot.

If there is a way I can see the status of the people in Excel itself that would be great!!!

I did use SIP to ping them from excel but would ease lot of work if I can see their availability/status in excel itself

Someone please advise!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in capability to display Skype for Business/Lync contact status inside any Microsoft Office applications besides Outlook.

VBA can be used to query Skype/Lync contact status, simply because VBA is awesome, but from your question I'm guessing that's not what you're looking for.

Answer (score -1):

There will be a solution for this in the near future. With the advent of data types in excel 2019 (and available now in the fast track program on O365) we will be able to get to the status if the databases connected include the exchange ones.